# delete bot message after 2 user messages prior

Tags: discord.js

javascript is still vague to my knowledge, and I cannot be precise on the sensibility in the following code I have manufactured. I am programming a discord bot that categorizes messages into a variety of channels, and the question has approached me to how I can program the bot by deleting follow up bot messages after 2 user messages were sent subsequently after the bot message.

```js
if (bot.on(client, user.msg = '2'));{
    msg.channel('message' = msg.delete)
}
```

Help is to be requested and I hope my query makes sense in the context I am implying, Regards, Coder

P.S: How do I change the bot messages text color as well?

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but your code was completely faulty, so I just made some new code.

```
bot.on('message', aysnc message => {
   var messagenumber = 0; //Makes variable for the number of messages sent

   if(message.member.user.username === bot.user.username) return; //If the person who posts a message is the bot, it doesn't the code below.
   if(messagenumber = 1) return bulkDelete(100), messagenumber = 0 //Checks if the variable is 1, and if it is, this means it's the second time a message posted, so it deletes messages (Limit is 100) then resets variable. 
   messagenumber = 1; //Makes variable 1 (This is to make it know it is the the second time a message is posted for the next time).
});
```

I didn't test this code, so it may not work properly, but if it does work I hope it helps you with your bot.

> For the P.S (Changing text color): You can use [these](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-change-the-text-color-in-Discord) (Replace "NoKeyWordsHere" with your message). I don't recommend this, cause it'd take a long time to add it to every message sent. (You can use these on your messages too)